# Multicast between server and client with or without a router not knowing server IP in advance and possible diferent sub-net

Tags: sockets, multicast, python-3.8, discovery

I'm writing in Python software that runs on my Windows (and Linux) PC, while the PC is connected via LAN **(with or without a router)** to a second device.

The second device sends UDP multicast packets to a known multicast group address and port.
The software in the computer is configured to be part of the same multicast group.
**This is working OK as long as both my computer and the server network configuration are on the same sub-net.**

Now, most of the times I will don't know the IP of the device in advance and I'll be connecting my computer directly to the server point-to-point. (Imagine the software that comes with IP security cameras that allows you to discover or know the IP of the camera when connecting directly to them with out knowing it in advance and without being in the same sub-net). E.g my computer has IP 169.x.x.x/24 and the server has IP 10.1.1.100 but I do not know the server IP in advance.

For reasons out of my control, the device cannot be configured to be a DHCP server so it cannot assign IP to my computer and cannot use DNS.

How can I receive the UDP multicast packets without raw capture?

This is my current code for the socket configuration that is working when both the computer and the server have the same sub-net. Ex 10.1.1.100/16 and 10.1.1.60/16 but needs to work also as mentioned above.

```
class MulticastSocket(object):
    """Sends UDP packets to multicast addressses."""

    def __init__(self, bind_ip=None):
        self._create(bind_ip)

    def _create(self, bind_ip):
        self.bind_addr = bind_ip

        # chosen arbitrary from IANA's Scoped Multicast Range
        # https://www.iana.org/assignments/multicast-addresses/multicast-addresses.xhtml#unicast-prefix-based
        self.multicast_group = '239.6.2.86'
        self.multicast_port = 6286

        """Creates a multicast UDP socket"""
        self._sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, socket.IPPROTO_UDP)
        self._sock.settimeout(6)
        ttl = 2
        self._sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_MULTICAST_TTL, ttl)
        
        self._sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_IP, socket.IP_MULTICAST_IF, socket.inet_aton(self.bind_addr))
        membership_request = struct.pack('4s4s', socket.inet_aton(self.multicast_group),
                                         socket.inet_aton(self.bind_addr))
        self._sock.setsockopt(
            socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, membership_request)

        self._sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

        
        if sys.platform == 'linux':
            bind_addr = self.multicast_group
        else:
            bind_addr = self.bind_addr if self.bind_addr else ''
        self._sock.bind((bind_addr, self.multicast_port))

    def get(self):
        """use to get the socket object to work with the select as select only accept sockets objects"""
        return self._sock

    def send(self, msg):
        return self._sock.sendto(msg, (self.multicast_group, self.multicast_port))

    def recv(self, len):
        try:
            response = self._sock.recvfrom(len)
            return response
        except socket.timeout:
            return "", ""

    def close(self):
        self._sock.close()
```

Comment: You don't need to know the server IP address in multicast. You need to know the multicast IP address. That's one of the points. The multicast receiver can also receive the source-address of each multicast. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @Marquis of Lorne, I'm new to socket and network configuration and happy to learn.
As mention I use multicast and have the same address in both the client and server but I do not receive the message when doing point to point connection with the server and the client having different subnets.

Comment: Then you need to ensure correct routing from the sender to the multicast address. If it's a device whose IP routing tables you can't configure, you may have no option but to use a router, or make the receiver a bridge. Fairly off topic.

Comment: @Marquis of Lorne, thank you for your replies.
I think this is possible with out routers.
As mention the example of devices like IP cameras where you do not know the configured factory IP but they come with a software, a discovery tool, that lets you connect your computer directly to the camera and it will find the IP of this camera even if it is on different subnet. 
I do not know how this discovery tool works but know the use multicast.
Again thanks for your help.

Comment: I suspect it works by receiving the multicasts.

Comment: Thanks Marquis. So If it works with multicast it means that I may have some bad configuration on my Multicast configuration code.
I publish it so you can see it and If I have a mistake or I'm totally in the wrong direction with my code the lovely people here, including you, could help me determine where it is so I can fix it.

Comment: Well (1) you shold bind your socket to INADDR_ANY, not a specific IP address, and (2) the correct setting for `IP_MULTICAST_IF` is any IP address that will route to the multicast-sending device. Quite possibly, or even probably, you don't need to set this option at all.